# Why isn't the Angular ng-click event firing?

Tags: angularjs

I've been following a course to learn angularjs and I can't seem to get a simple `ng-click` binding to work.

**HTML:**

```
<body ng-controller="MainController">

    <div ng-app="githubViewer">

        <h1>{{message}}</h1>

        <div>{{ error }}</div>

        {{username}}

        <form name="searchUser">
            <input type="search" placeholder="Username to find" ng-model="username" />
            <input type="submit" value="Search" ng-click="search(username)" />
        </form>

        <div>
            <div>{{user.name}}</div>
            <img ng-src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/{{user.gravatar_id}}" title="{{user.name}}">
            {{user.gravatar_id}}
        </div>

    </div>

</body>
```

**Javascript:**

```
(function () {

    var module = angular.module("githubViewer", []);

    var MainController = function ($scope, $http) {

        var onUserComplete = function (response) {
            $scope.user = response.data;
        };

        var onError = function (reason) {
            $scope.error = "Could not fetch the user";
            $scope.reason = reason;
        };

        $scope.username = "angular";
        $scope.message = "Github Viewer";

        $scope.search = function (username) {
            $http.get("https://api.github.com/users/" + username)
                .then(onUserComplete, onError);
        };
    };

    module.controller("MainController", MainController);

}());
```

When you click the search button (search for username "odetocode" or "robconery") it is supposed to display an image but the click event does not seem to be firing.  I have searched the documentation and looked over the course again but I can't see what I'm doing wrong.

I'm currently using version 1.2.16 of angularjs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the `ng-controller` declaration outside of the `ng-app` declaration right now:

```
<body ng-controller="MainController">

    <div ng-app="githubViewer">
```

It should be the other way around, or have both on the same element

```
<body ng-app="githubViewer" ng-controller="MainController">

    <div>
```

AngularJS evaluates your code, and checks for any directives you have declared from the `ng-app` element down, including the element it is declared on; This currently is missing the `ng-controller` directive, as it is placed on a parent element of the `ng-app` element.

Comment: Good spot.  Thanks for that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the controller within the context of the module to have it within its scope.

Like so

```
<body ng-app="githubViewer" ng-controller="MainController">
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/doiks14/UA9hV/)